# Best way to implement SSO with .net applications

Tags: active-directory, adfs

I have to implement Single Sign on with following user case:
We have three kinds of users:

1)  Corporate employees [Stored in Active directory]
2)  Clients can access our application 
3)  We have hosted separate application for each client and clients employees can access this application [hosted on our server] and number of employees can be have million.
So we cannot store use credentials in active directory because we need per user license to use.

Please help me to find better solutions

Answer (score 0):

ADFS only works with AD. The next version of ADFS will work against LDAP so that's a possibility.

I would look at Azure Active Directory (you could use something like AAD Sync. to migrate your existing AD users) or something like OpenAM or PingFederate (both of which are Java based) which you have to pay for or something like shibboleth (Java based but open source). These all support LDAP.

Or if you want to go the SQL Server route, look at thinktecture's identityserver.